# Windows 10 hangs for 1 second while typing

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze, troubleshooting

My laptop recently started having an unusual issue: whenever I'm typing, it will randomly freeze for about 0.5 to 2 seconds, after that, it will resume working and also catch up on all the text I've written since.
Please note that since the freeze is so quick, it might just be an impression that it only happens while typing. I know for a fact that it does not stop audio or video playing.

It happens on any application where you can type, including any browser (Chrome, Edge, FFox), messaging app or text editor.

It happens randomly so it's very hard to trubleshoot, although my general impression is that the frequency increases if RAM usage is > 25%.
For example the frequency seems to increase a lot if I open Chrome or a heavy IDE.

**What I have tried:**

- Check windows files for integrity with `sfc /scannow`:  No problems found
- Updating keyboard, audio and video drivers from manufacter website: All were up to date
- Clean boot (disabling all services except microsoft): Nothing changed
- Ram memory diagnostic (the tool that comes with windows): No problems found
- Clean cache, delete temp files
- Reset winsock registry (`netsh winsock reset`): Nothing changed
- Windows Update: all done
- Undo any recent hardware or software changes: I haven't changed anything in weeks, except for updating a few drivers that were otherwise causing a BSOD. This however happened about 5-6 days before the freezing problem occurred, and I hadn't changed anything since.
- Disabling "turn off Hard Drive after.." in advanced power settings
- Setting manual virtual memory, minimal at recommended value and maximum at 1.5 times my total RAM

Any idea? I'm lost at this point.

**Useful Specs:**

```
Keyboard: Integrated laptop keyboard
Laptop: Alienware 17R3 

Windows 10 Home 1709 Build: 16299.248 (Updated from .225)

SSD (C:, OS) 500GB, 150 GB avaiable

HDD (D:) 1TB, 250GB avaiable data only

Ram: 16GB DDR4 (8x2)
NVIDIA GTX 980M lastest drivers
```

Laptop froze about 6 times while writing this post.

Comment: Is the keyboard with trouble the internal keyboard or one that you have plugged in to the laptop? If the latter, is it wireless? You also didn’t tell us what make and model of laptop you have.

Comment: @Appleoddity It's the integrated keyboard. Laptop is an Alienware 17R3, I updated the post, sorry.

Comment: install [last Windows 10 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074588), which fixes GDI perf issues

Comment: @magicandre1981Ok, installing it now manually. Could you please elaborate on what exactly it does?

Comment: Installed, nothing changed, still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Try to delete Alienware On Screen Display application. This couse sometimes problems to user . Maybe reducing the [keyboard buffer size](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976200.aspx) helps.I would like to know what [DPC Latency Checker](https://www.heise.de/download/product/dpc-latency-checker-52865) gives you.

Comment: So I found the reason causing this annoying issue, but don't know how to fix it. If you remove the driver on the mouse/touch pad and revert it back to the PS/2 basic driver it will not lag. I ran it like this for a few hours and it worked perfect, minus the lack of touchpad functionality, and the mouse cursor moved really slow.. I tried re installing the proper synaptic driver after a restart and it did the whole annoying lag thing again.. Not sure how to proceed without keeping the basic ps/2 driver in place.. Hopefully this helps, and someone a lot smarter can take this further.. Same setup

Comment: @Medictrode I was actually able to fix the issue recently while keeping the driver. I just disabled "Scp Virtual Bus" from Device Manager > System devices. Turns out, it was interfering with "Logitech Virtual Bus" (which I also disabled since I was desperate, but have since re-enabled and hasn't given issues). I also removed the synaptic additional software just to be sure. I hope this helps.